# Showing properties of inverse and direct image of quasicoherent sheaves via Yoneda's lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, sheaf-theory, adjoint-functors, quasicoherent-sheaves

Disclaimer: A question about the same result has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309389/inverse-image-of-the-sheaf-associated-to-a-module) previously. See my comment at the bottom for why I think this question is unique.

Let $\phi: A \longrightarrow B$ be a morphism of rings with corresponding morphism of affine schemes, $f: \text{Spec }B \longrightarrow \text{Spec }A$. I will denote $Y = \text{Spec }B$ and $X = \text{Spec }A$. Let $N$ be a $B$-module and denote by $_A{N}$ the module $N$ when treated as an $A$-module via the map $\phi$. As usual, let $\widetilde{N}$ denote the sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{Y}$-modules corresponding to $N$.

I have proved the following, so throughout my question it can be assumed:

> Theorem 1: If $M$ is an $A$-module, with other notation from above, then there is an adjunction between restriction of scalars and change of rings. In particular, there is a natural bijection,
>   $$
> \hom_{A}(M, (_{A}N) ) \simeq \hom_{B}(B \otimes_{A} M, N).
> $$

I would like to prove that $f_{*}(\widetilde{N}) \simeq (_A{N})^{\sim}$. This is Hartshorne Proposition II 5.2 (d). There he claims that this "follows directly from the definitions", although I can't see how. Is anyone able to explain how it follows directly from the definition?

In any case, I have been attempting to prove this via adjunction arguments and the Yoneda lemma, and I wanted to know if people could help me finish my attempt, and also tell me if such a method is even valid. To begin, for any sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules $\mathcal{F}$, define the presheaf 
$$
\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{F}}: U \mapsto f^{-1} \mathcal{F}(U) \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)} \mathcal{O}_{Y}.
$$
Then the sheafification of this, denoted $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{F}}^{+}$ is precisely the inverse image sheaf $f^{*} \mathcal{F}$.

I claim that in order to prove what I want, Yoneda's lemma tells me it is sufficient to find a natural bijection
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \big(  \mathcal{F}, (_AN)^{\sim} \big) \simeq \hom_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \big( \mathcal{F}  , f_{*}(\widetilde{N})  \big).
$$
To do this, we begin with the well known adjunction $f^{*} \dashv f_{*}$ to write
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \big( \mathcal{F}  , f_{*}(\widetilde{N})  \big) \simeq \hom_{\mathcal{O}_{Y}} \big(  f^{*}\mathcal{F}, \widetilde{N} \big).
$$
Then by the universal property for sheafification, we have another natural bijection,
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{O}_{Y}} \big(  f^{*}\mathcal{F}, \widetilde{N} \big) \simeq \hom \big( \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{F}}, \widetilde{N}   \big).
$$
At this point I'd like to make some argument on global sections using Theorem 1 above. Is anyone able to give me an idea how to finish this, and whether or not this is even valid up to this point? I am new to Yoneda's lemma and adjoints so I'm not entirely comfortable that it's even correct.

I mentioned at the top that a question has been asked on this result before. The reason I am asking this here is that the answer given to that question uses the fact that there is an equivalence of categories $\mathsf{Mod}A \simeq \mathsf{QCoh}(X)$. However, this result is not proved until later in Hartshorne, and indeed the proof seems to use the very fact I am trying to prove here.